# Flutter app is running on Android Emulator but not on Physical Device (OnePlus 7T)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart

When I run my flutter app on Android Emulator it runs without errors but when I am running it on my mobile device it shows following error in Debug Console:

Launching lib\main.dart on HD1901 in debug mode...
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'arm64_v8a_debug.jar (io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Bharat\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\arm64_v8a_debug\1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408\b829535c84919575c5e7bfe4ebb08763a01eceec\arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar.

         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\Bharat\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\arm64_v8a_debug\1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408\b829535c84919575c5e7bfe4ebb08763a01eceec\arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: invalid entry size (expected 27494264 but got 27496386 bytes). (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Output for 'flutter doctor -v' with device connected:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (4 days ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Bharat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Bharat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Bharat\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • HD1901 • 90801aca • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

• No issues found!
```

App level 'build.gradle' file's content:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.bbayshop_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Project level 'build.gradle' file's content:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also including 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file's content:

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: post your "flutter doctor -v" with your device connected

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Thank you for replying. I have posted the output of "flutter doctor -v" with my device connected.

Comment: looks like it may be something over the cache build. Did you tried "flutter clean" before running on your device?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Yes I tried it but still same error. Plz help :(

Comment: did you added libraries to your project? post your app level build.gradle file as well

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I have added app level 'build.gradle' file's content alongwith project level 'build.gradle' and also 'gradle-wrapper.properties' content.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I added http, intl, provider dependencies in my project. Adding some more info, yesterday flutter upgrade came and then i upgraded flutter at same moment but today when I am running my app in android device its not running. Before the upgrade (before yesterday) whenever I ran on my physical device it ran. But today before testing in my mobile I also did changes in my app level build.gradle to generate an apk file (I followed the steps from this site : https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android ) and just after that undo the steps and returned back and then tested on mobile.

Comment: try by changing min sdk  version to 23

Comment: @iamyadunandan I tried, but still same error :(

Comment: Have you set they jetifier = true ?

Comment: @iamyadunandan Yes, android.enableJetifier=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just delete all the contents in the ".gradle" folder located in C:\Users\.gradle\ 
If it shows that the files are open and can't be deleted, just open Task Manager, go to Details tab and locate 'java.exe'
Right click on each 'java.exe' and click End process tree. After all the java.exe processes are ended, go back to ".gradle" folder and delete all the contents.
That's it. :)