# Flutter - not able to run in android device

Tags: android, flutter

Hi I am getting this error while run without debugging my project in android device.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'arm64_v8a_debug.jar (io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54)' to match attributes 
{artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for IdentityTransform: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\arm64_v8a_debug\1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54\d84df37647d9c0eb0da1f86ba05744d618192eb7\arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:     

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.    

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 40s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        42.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I used connectivity plugin in my code, and error message says that, when I trying to run flutter build apk

```
Note: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-0.4.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

**Update :** I am able to run it in samsung j7, but I am getting the above error in samsung a7

Code I used to check connectivity

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
class NetworkConnection{
  Future<String> checkInternetConnectivity(BuildContext context) async
  {
    var result = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    String connection = "unknown";
    if(result == ConnectivityResult.none)
    {    
      //_showToast(context,"No Connectivity");
      connection =  "not connected";
    }
    else if(result == ConnectivityResult.mobile)
    {
      try {
            final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
            if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
              connection =  "connected";
            }
          } on SocketException catch (_) {
            connection =  "not connected";
          }

      //_showToast(context,"Connected to mobile");

    }
    else if(result == ConnectivityResult.wifi)
    {
      try {
            final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
            if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
              connection = "connected";
            }
          } on SocketException catch (_) {
            connection =  "not connected";
          }
      //_showToast(context,"Connected to wifi");
    
    }
    return connection;
  }
}
```

My flutter doctor -v looks like this

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1016], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.20.2 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision bbfbf1770c (7 days ago), 2020-08-13 08:33:09 -0700
    • Engine revision 9d5b21729f
    • Dart version 2.9.1

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 48.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.6911.31

[√] VS Code (version 1.48.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.2

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM A750F (mobile) • 32008575eabc85fb • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
```

This is my **build.gradle** file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.sfav1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean`?

Comment: @SanjaySharma I tried no luck!

Comment: Are you using the latest package version `connectivity: ^0.4.9` ? If yes and problem yet persists please provide the line of code you`re using this package.

Comment: @Taba I have added my code. I am using latest version of connectivity package.

Comment: how's your `flutter doctor` looking?

Comment: @ByteMe I downgraded my flutter to 1.17.5 for that its working, but for latest package only I am getting this error.

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012389/flutter-app-is-running-on-android-emulator-but-not-on-physical-device-oneplus-7

Comment: refactoring point: wrap the try block into a method and call it on both "else if"s.

Comment: @Watth Can you please post that code? will that solve my problem?

Comment: @ByteMe I have added my flutter doctor - v in this question.

Comment: from the look of it, this doesn't seem to be an issue with the connectivity plugin

Comment: @Anu, did my answer work?

Comment: @ByteMe I added my gradle file in question section. I updated my flutter to 1.20.2 but still connectivity warning exists.

Comment: @Anu: It will just improve code structure and readability.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not set the Permission `Internet` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Look into this [Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31834).

Comment: I added permission, still facing the same issue.

Comment: i updated flutter to new stable version is that the reason i am having this problem??  @frankenapps

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these settings to your `defaultConfig` on `android/app/build.gradle`

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
ndk {
    abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
}
```

e.g.:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.0.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your code but sill I am getting this warning Note: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-0.4.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: @Anu are you able to run on your samsung a7? this is just a warning, to solve this you would need create an issue on the project's github and wait, or make a pull request solving this issue yourself. But I don't think that this warning is causing your problem at all.

Comment: Yes the warning is not should stop the app from compiling. Look at my answer for more details

Comment: @Vitor I am able to run after upgrading my flutter version from 1.20.1 to 1.20.2. In 1.20.1 i was not able to take build. But now its working. Can you please add some details in your answer. It will help all!

Comment: @ByteMe yes it should not be a problem, but when I take a split apk for target platform my app is crashing. While i took apk in 1.20.1 network was not detected even if i connected to internet. Thats why i am worried about this warning!

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Samsung A7 is an Android 10 (API 29). Howeever, the `build.gradle` automatically generated by flutter doesn't target API 29.

You can change this by updating the following line in your `android\app\build.gradle` file.

Run `flutter run` after updating the file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29  //change compileSdkVersion to 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.new_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29  //this line: change 28 to 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

}
```

As for the deprecation warning, apparently the [warning is common](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50870#issuecomment-586757016_) in some plugins developed by the flutter team but it shouldn't affect the compiling of your flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** as per you have used **Packages** in your project i.e. in **pubspec.yaml** file.

i.e.

```
defaultConfig {
    .
    .
    .      
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    .
    .
}
```